# Rooted SGS3 and Kies doesn't work with my ROM, Looking for contact list files

Tags: cyanogenmod, contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-kies

Recently rooted my SGS3 and installed a custom ROM, so I had to import my contacts number back into my phone and I had them saved as a vcard... When I imported all the names, I thought it had buggered up so I imported them again, now there are two of every name and it's a very lengthy process to manually remove every 2nd name (I have 800+ contacts). I'm trying to find a way to remove my contacts completely, but seeing as Kies and Kies Air don't work properly with this ROM, I'm trying to locate the path in my phone that has the contact files so I can remove them that way. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about Google contacts? In that case you could try Google's web frontend for cleanup. The result should then automatically be done by sync.

Comment: Nah, was talking about contacts stored on my phone, I ended up downloading one of those "Delete all contact" apps off the playstore then deleted all my contacts out of google and loaded my vcard list back into google then syncing it to google.

Comment: Umpf... Very close to my suggestion :) Would you mind to make this an answer (maybe with a few more details on the process), and accept it lateron? So people with a similar problem can easier identify it as "question with a solution".